# Magento 1.7 Database Error Category Flat Data

Tags: magento, phpmyadmin

After adding a number of products on my website this error came forward.

> problem with reindexing process Category Flat Data

Solutions on this website didn't work for me.
The errors in my log files are:

> General error: 1005 Can't create table 
>   catalog_category_flat_store_1' (errno: 150)

Do you have a solution for me?

Thnx!

Comment: - I deleted my .lock files in var/locks  didn't work

Comment: Error Code: 1005 -- there is a wrong primary key reference in your code.Any chance you remove any column key while modifying code.

Comment: did you modify any column keys while developing your site.

Comment: We were just adding some products to the website. Error in the exeption log: 
2013-03-19T20:28:59+00:00 DEBUG (7): Exception message: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table 'a1_6194d72e.kc4e_catalog_category_flat_store_1' (errno: 150)

Comment: looks like your connection user does not have sufficient permission to create a data base table

Comment: How can i set these permission to the right ones?

Comment: my exeptionlog is:
2013-03-19T20:28:59+00:00 DEBUG (7): Exception message: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table 'a1_6194d72e.kc4e_catalog_category_flat_store_1' (errno: 150)
Trace: 
#0 /home/vhosts/schoonheidonline.nl/httpdocs/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
#1 /home/vhosts/schoonheidonline.nl/httpdocs/lib/Zend/Db/Statement.php(300): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
#2 /home/vhosts/schoonheidonline.nl/httpdocs/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(479): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)

and so long....

Comment: you need to first check if this is the issue.I suggest you create that table via phpMyAdmin and check

Comment: I can not fix this :-(

Comment: @n2209h has you found any solution.

Comment: Try to remove all category flat tables from database

Answer (score -1):

I did a quick search and found this:

http://www.fortwaynewebdevelopment.com/magento-general-error-1005-cant-create-table-fixworkaround/

> ALTER TABLE catalog_category_entity ENGINE=INNODB;
>
> ALTER TABLE core_store ENGINE=INNODB;

Not sure if it will help at all with your issue.

Comment: This answer doesn't answer the question, try and provide answers that offer a solution and an explanation